# Can I use if-else for filereader

Tags: java, eclipse

Can I use if-else statement for filereader? I tried to use '==' but it doesn't seem to work. 
I'm sorry if the question is a bit unintelligent, as I'm new to Java.

Thank You!

```
String Path = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
readFile = new FileReader(Path + "/src/agents_chats_analytics.csv");
br = new BufferedReader(readFile);
...
if(readFile == new FileReader(Path+"/src/agents_chats_analytics.csv");))
 {
   // do stuffs
 }
else if(readFile == new FileReader(Path+"/src/department_agents.csv");)
 {
   // do stuffs
 }
...
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to read 3 excel files. If the file matches the readFile, it will run the codes if not it will move on to the next else if

Comment: I think you might want `File`.  Use `File newFile = new File( Path, "/src/etc." );` to concatenate two file paths together.  Then use `newFile.getName()` to get a string with the last file element in the path.

Comment: What do you mean by "If the file matches the readFile" ? What file? what does matches the readFile mean?

Comment: @Oleg just now - `if(readFile == new FileReader(Path+"/src/agents_chats_analytics.csv");))` matches with `readFile = new FileReader(Path + "/src/agents_chats_analytics.csv");` then if will run the code

Comment: In short, no this way. What are you comparing? Could you describe the meaning of your conditions with words? I assume you need simply String comparison.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: @SergeiSirik - Yes, i tried to use String comparison, but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

So, It was really hard to understand what you are trying to achieve, but, I guess, I got you right, so you can do it this way:

```
    String Path = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
    String readedFilePath = Path + "/src/agents_chats_analytics.csv";
    FileReader readFile = new FileReader(readedFilePath);

    if (readedFilePath.equals(Path + "/src/agents_chats_analytics.csv")) {
        readFile = new FileReader(Path + "/src/agents_chats_analytics.csv");
        // do stuffs
    } else if (readedFilePath.equals(Path + "/src/agents_chats_analytics.csv")) {
        readFile = new FileReader(Path + "/src/agents_chats_analytics.csv");
        // do stuffs
    }
```

You need to compare pathes not file readers. 
Also, logical equality of object types in java should be done using `equals` method and not "`==`" operator. "`==`" will compare object references, so in your case such comparison always gives `false`.